# How can i delete previous BufferedImages from Graphics stack in Java?

Tags: java, bufferedimage

My problem is quite simple to understand. I have a JPanel inside a JFrame in order to display some graphics using the drawFormula() method below to display 3d points in screen using perspective projection. Everytime drawFormula() reaches its end I just recall itself to draw the shape again and again and again and because I dont want to have any image flickering problems I dont use the paintComponent method but i call drawImage() method from panelG which I get from this.getGraphics() method of my JPanel. Everything runs fine, but the problem is that after a certain amount of time it stops rendering and i believe that it has to do with the list of BufferedImages it holds everytime i call drawImage(). Is there a way to remove the previous not needed images from the stack? Thanks in advance!

```
public void drawFormula(){

    for(double i=latMin;i<latMax;i+= 0.05){
        for(double j=longMin;j<longMax;j+= 0.05){

            calc(m,n1,n2,n3,i,j);

            applyRotationX();
            applyRotationY();
            applyRotationZ();


            if(outX>xxmin && outX<xxmax && outY>yymin && outY<yymax){
                xxx = (int)((outX-xxmin)*xinc);
                yyy = (int)((outY-yymin)*yinc);
                zzz = (int)((outZ-zzmin)*zinc);

                //img_g.drawRect(xxx, yyy, 1, 1);
                //img_g.drawRect((int) (planeX.getOffset(new Vector3D(xxx,yyy,zzz)))+600,(int) (planeY.getOffset(new Vector3D(x[i],y[i],z[i])))+350+j,1,1);
                //img_g.setColor(new Color(Color.HSBtoRGB((float)(outX/outY), (float)(outY), (float)(outZ))));

                drawPoint(xxx, yyy, zzz);

                //panelG.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
            }
        }
    }

    //panelG.dispose();
    //panelG = getGraphics().create();

    panelG.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);



    thetaX += 1;
    thetaX %= 360;


    img_g.setColor(Color.black);
    img_g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    drawFormula();

}
```

Comment: Please create and post a small but simple complete program that illustrates your problem, an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please check the link for the details of this very useful tool. I've not heard that calling `getGraphics()` on a component is a way to reduce flickering, but I do know that it can result in unstable images since the Graphics object so obtained is very transient and risks going bad.

Comment: Maybe you should call dispose() on Graphics object (it will free all resources grabbed by this object) and next you can create Graphics object once again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it stops rendering due to a stackoverflow. You have an unconditioned recursion in your code (the `drawFormula()` at the end of drawFormula), which will cause a stackoverflow at some point. For the flickering: use `setDoubleBuffered(true),` this should solve your problem aswell.

Comment: If this is the case, shouldn't the program throw a StackOverflowError? Good pick up on the unconditioned recursion though. That certainly is a bad idea.

Comment: @Paul Ouch ,u are right! I should have used a while loop instead .Sry for your time guys...It works!! :P and it seems that there is no stack for images ... It just mixes the bufferedImages to a final one. Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @PeGiannOS: then why are you not seeing a StackOverflowError? You don't have any empty catch blocks in your code, do you?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels , well it seems strange ... The only thing i can find suspicious is that i call drawFormula in a SwingWorker for the first time inside its doInBackground method

Comment: @PeGiannOS: that is dangerous coding since you'll then be making critical Swing calls from within a background thread. Your code design worries me. And I know why you're not seeing the exception method -- you are not likely calling the SwingWorker's `get()` method, and so have no way of being notified of exceptions that occur from within `doInBackground()`. You should **always** call the `get()` method even if it returns nothing if just for this purpose. I usually do this from within a PropertyChangeListener that listens for the worker's SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE.